# Increase the number of bookmarks in a QGIS project

Tags: qgis, qgs, bookmarks

In QGIS 3.0 and 2.18 there is apparently a limited number of bookmarks, that can be stored. It is a limit of 250 bookmarks per project.
I find bookmarks great for an in-project team coomunication and I need to change that limit somehow, as we reached it.
Made a lot of how-to research and didn't found anything similar. The only path I found possible is to change "something" in the Advanced Settings Editor.

Does someone know how to change the limit of possible bookmarks in a QGIS project?

Comment: Are you receiving a message letting you know you've reached a limit, if so what is the message?

Comment: No, it just simply swaps the new bookmark with the last bookmark added. No notifications, no messages.